# selecting first radio button via selenium (java)

Tags: java, selenium

I would like to select the first radio button on a web page via selenium (java) - I only have the value for the radio button and I know its the first button in the list of radio buttons.  What would be the best approach for selecting this radio button - any helpful suggestions would be welcome.
I tried the following but it does not work (radio button has value of 1):

```
selenium.check("value=1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use the following which worked:

```
  selenium.click("//input[@value='1']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this :

```
List<WebElement> inputList=driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));

for(int i=0;i<inputList.size();i++)
{

    if (inputList.get(i).getAttribute("type").equalsIgnoreCase("radio"))
    {
        if(inputList.get(i).getAttribute("value").equals("1"))
        {
            inputList.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: firstly,we are finding all the inputs tag present in the page. Then we are finding weather the input tag selected is a radio box or not.After that we are checking the value of the radio box weather it is equal to 1 or not. If it is we are clicking on that particular radio box.